# IF command keeps running even when there is no input

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I am trying to make a project where a number is sent to serial via a python program. Then an Arduino is to read the number and perform a specific function (here printing something on an lcd) for a specified duration. However the code doesn't work as intended.

Here is the code running on the Arduino:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

boolean flag1, flag2;

const int rs = 3, en = 2, d4 = 4, d5 = 5, d6 = 6, d7 = 7;

LiquidCrystal lcd(rs, en, d4, d5, d6, d7);

String a;

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.print("hello");
  delay(1000);
  lcd.clear();
}

void loop() {

  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);

    if(Serial.available())
    {
        int c = Serial.read();
        if(c == 49) { // 1 is pressed
            flag1 = true;
            flag2 = false;
        }
        else if(c == 50) { // 2 is pressed
            flag2 = true;
            flag1 = false;
        }
    }
    if(flag1) {
        lcd.write("location 1");
        delay(3000);
        lcd.clear();
        
    }
    if(flag2) {
        lcd.write("location 2");
        delay(3000);
        lcd.clear();
    }
    delay(50);
}
```

When the number is pressed it shows the text however it keeps it on the screen forever. I need it to run once (for the specified delay duration) then reset to blank screen. When another number is entered, it changes the text but again keeps it on forever.

Comment: read through your code carefully. it should be obvious that you're clearing the display for 50 milliseconds befor you write the same content again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear the flag after reading it:

```
if(flag1) {
    flag1 = false;
    // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you send your first characters, the if statements that write to your LCD are already being evaluated. Unfortunately, your flags haven't been initialized. I would suggest:

```
boolean flag1 = false, flag2 = false;
```

at the top of the file.